# Dynamically set up the version_locations in env.py for alembic migrations

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, migration, alembic

I am using alembic to manage my database changes.
Other people may also add changes to this database.
Everything is set up correctly and this is currebtly working fine.
However, because we are many to modify the db and therefore create new .py for each modifications, I wanted to move the "version" folder away from my github repo to avoid flooding it.
The version folder would then be accessible to a distant server.
We can acess the server from our local machines via sshfs therefore guy1 may have the server to /mnt/myserver, and guy2 to /home/myserver.

I would like then to be able to change the version_locations to `path_to_server/versions`. I didnt manage to do so using the env.py to do it dynamically. Any idea on how to do so ?

So far the plan was:

```
my_server_path = os.environ.get("my_server_path")
context.script.version_locations = f"{my_server_path}/versions"
```

I've also tried with `config.set_main_option("version_locations",f"{my_server_path}/versions")`
and to change the `revision_environment` in the alembic.ini to true or false, but didnt work either.

At best I had alembic telling me `FAILED: Multiple version locations present, please specify --version-path`, but it doesnt make sense to specify a path when there should only be one in the beginning.